# Verificar si ya existe usuario y email en la base de datos php

Tags: php, sql

Estoy creando un formulario de registro para usuarios y quiero evitar que se guarden datos duplicados en la base de datos.

mas específicamente que solo pueda existir un usuario con X nombre y un usuario con X correo.

pude validar con éxito si uno de los datos ya existe en la base de datos
pero no he podido hacer la validación para ambos datos.

si bien de pronto es algo básico para algunos, soy prácticamente principiante en cuanto a php y espero que alguien con mas experiencia pueda ayudarme con el problema.

gracias de antemano

mi código php actual es el siguiente:

```html
<?php

//recibir datos
$nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$email =  $_POST['Email'];
$pass = $_POST['Pass'];

$hash = md5($pass);


//comprobacion datos duplicados
$consulta_db_duo = $conect_my_db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE NAME=:nombre_d");
$consulta_db_duo -> bindParam(":nombre_d", $nombre);
$consulta_db_duo -> execute();

if($consulta_db_duo -> rowCount()>=1){
    echo '<script language="javascript">
            alert("Este nombre ya esta siendo usado");
        </script>';
}else{
    
    //preparar consulta
    $consulta_db_reg = $conect_my_db -> prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (NAME, EMAIL, PASS) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $consulta_db_reg -> bindParam(1, $nombre);
    $consulta_db_reg -> bindParam(2, $email);
    $consulta_db_reg -> bindParam(3, $hash);
    
    // ejecutar consulta
    if($consulta_db_reg -> execute()){
        echo '<script language="javascript">
                alert("Te has registrado con exito");
            </script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script language="javascript">
                alert("Ha ocurrido un error durante el registro, por favor intenta nuevamente");
            </script>';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
//comprobacion datos duplicados
$consulta_db_duo = $conect_my_db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE NAME=:nombre_d AND EMAIL=:email_d;");
$consulta_db_duo -> bindParam(":nombre_d", $nombre);
$consulta_db_duo -> bindParam(":email_d", $email);
$consulta_db_duo -> execute();
```

Ahora el problema es que si escriben otro nombre será tomado como valido para registrase, asi que seria mejor, para bien de tus datos, validar que únicamente el correcto no se repita en tu tabla de usuarios.

```
//comprobacion datos duplicados
$consulta_db_duo = $conect_my_db -> prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE EMAIL=:email_d;");
$consulta_db_duo -> bindParam(":email_d", $email);
$consulta_db_duo -> execute();
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, logre hacer lo que quería pero de una forma diferente. hice una consulta para nombre y otra consulta para email.

y valide todo con condicionales if else.

Comment: @Luccyan que bien, ¿lograste hacerlo con una sola llamada a la base de datos?

Comment: no.  hice 2 consultas, me funciono pero bueno debe haber una forma de lograrlo con una sola consulta, igual todo es aprendizaje.  

espero mas adelante aprender una mejor forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Para ello usa "or" en lugar de "and", "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE EMAIL=:email_d OR NAME=:nombre_d;", lo cual te devolverá un arreglo y puedes iterar sobre él y hacer que, por ejemplo, correo_existe=false; nombre_existe=false; cambien en cuanto se encuentren sus respectivas condiciones y luego de eso revisas que correo_existe y nombre_existe sean ambos falsos para poder continuar correctamente.

Comment: Para estas cosas también es importante que en el esquema de BBDD tengas el correo como único. De esta manera, si intentas guardar algún dato repetido, te dará el error de inserción correspondiente y aseguras tu BBDD.

Answer (score 0):

Luccyan, te recomendaria ver este enlace, para cambiar el hash que le proporcionas a tus contraseñas. Uno llamado bcrypt.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: gracias por la sugerencia, me informare mas sobre el tema.